# A bug Integrating Piecewise functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

I have found a very puzzling bug (version 12.0), where integrating the sum of a piecewise function with a `DiracDelta` with a variable integration limit causes errors, but integrating each summand separately does not:

```
$Assumptions = {X > 1};
u[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x < 1}, {2, x >= 1}}]
Integrate[u[r], {r, 0, X}]
Integrate[DiracDelta[r - 1], {r, 0, X}]
Integrate[u[r] + DiracDelta[r - 1], {r, 0, X}]
```

[image: Output]

I have computed these integrals successfully until yesterday, when suddenly it just stopped working (and no restarts are helping). Adding assumptions inside `Integrate[]` doesn't change the output.

Comment: @Nasser  `r-1>0` would be wrong. You probably meant `X>1`, but adding that doesn't change anything.

Comment: You are right, that assumption does not work. deleting comment. Will check something else.

Comment: may be there is a bug. Try this `ClearAll[X, x, r];
u[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x < 1}, {2, x >= 1}}];
Integrate[u[r] + DiracDelta[r - 1], {r, 0, 3}]` which gives strange output.

Comment: Since you are adding the terms, can you not do this? `ClearAll[X, x, r];
$Assumptions = {X > 1};
u[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x < 1}, {2, x >= 1}}];
Integrate[u[r], {r, 0, X}] + Integrate[DiracDelta[r - 1], {r, 0, X}]`  Now it works with no error.

Comment: Please read the [tag:bugs] info before using it.

Comment: There is no relation with  definite integral of  integrand which includes $\delta$-distribution in https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Generalized_function and W.Rudin, Functional analysis,McGrow-Hill, New-York-..-Toronto. 1973.

Comment: @Nasser that's exactly my point. Why would `Integrate[f+g]` not produce the same output as `Integrate[f]+Integrate[g]`.

Comment: @level1807  it might be a bug. You could send email to support@wolfram.com and see what they say. Although the normal use of dirac delta under the integral is to multiply it by another function and not to add it.